# What is the easiest way to create a simple client for MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, client

In our curriculum new students with a little programming experience in Java will learn how to design and use a MySQL-database. What is the easiest way for them to create a client program that interacts with the database? I'm not looking for a PHPmyAdmin kind of solution, but something which lets you create an end-user client.

For example, they have a database with products, orders and orderlines. The client must be able to insert a new order with orderlines, but must not be able to edit the existing products.

Comment: What do you mean "generate a client"?

Comment: Do you want a UI for them to test queries?

Comment: You could use an existing http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Java+open+source+SQL+client 21 million hits.

Comment: Are you looking for a simple implementation of a a program like this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phpmyadmin ? Probably something that can be done by students as pat of coursework?

Comment: Sequel Pro if their on a mac http://www.sequelpro.com/. By far the easiest client to work with.

Comment: Rewrote the question a bit, hopefully it's a bit clearer this way.

Comment: What is the focus of your curriculum, the frontend or the backend with services and database design, and if its the database design, is then the focus on using SQL or maybe using an OR mapper?

Comment: The focus is on the database and SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like NetBeans can generate a database application based on an existing database, see [tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-db.html). Example is for JavaDB but it should work with any DB for which you have a JDBC driver. Never tried it myself thought.